# "I was starting suspecting something was wrong" <-- What's the grammar problem here?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, gerund-vs-infinitive

I have been using “starting suspecting” frequently thinking that it’s correct too but recently my friend corrected me. I don't understand why.

It is well-known that *start to + verb* and *start verb-ing* are interchangeable in terms of meaning:

> 1. It started to rain.
> 2. It started raining.

The sentences above mean the same thing.

There is also no problem with the verb *suspect* being used as a gerund-participle:

Consider:

- I started suspecting something was amiss.

There is no problem with using the verb *start* in continuous cobstructions:

- It was starting to rain.

So what's the grammatical problem with the folowing?

> 3. I was starting suspecting that something was amiss.

Comment: John Ross wrote a well known linguistics paper "Double Ing" on how to tell whether two consecutive -ing words are acceptable  (I can't locate a web reference right now -- it appeared in a Chicago Linguistic Society volume.) Here is a previous SE discussion: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44078/two-consecutive-gerunds-ing-ing

Comment: @tchrist This any good for a reopen now?

Comment: Are you also asking what is wrong with "It was starting raining."? Because that has the same problem, but you've not mentioned it.

Comment: @GregLee This? [PDF]Doubl-ing.
files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED058768.pdf
by JR Ross - ‎1971 - ‎Cited by 146 - ‎Related articles
FL 002 718. Ross, John Robert. Doubl-ing. Language Research Foundation, Cambridge, Mass. National. Inst. of Mental Health (DHEW). Bethesda,. Md.; National Science Foundation, Washington, D.C.. Jul 71. 51p.; In Language Research Report No. 4. MF-$0.65 HC-$3.29. Ambiguity; Deep Structure; Descriptive Linguistics ...

Comment: @MetaEd, Yes, or see the reference given above by user159691.

Comment: This does look like a duplicate of the linked question. The linked question could use some help.

Comment: @GregLee Yes. The linked question has an answer by Lawler which credits Ross. The link I posted is to the Ross paper itself in case you want to refer to it.

Answer (score -1):

*"I was starting suspecting that something was amiss."*
First off "was starting" is **passive** and **redundant**. From every definition I saw,  *Present perfect progressive tense describes an action that began in the past, continues in the present, and may continue into the future.* [1](https://leo.stcloudstate.edu/grammar/tenses.html) So anything I'm "doing" the fact that I "*was* doing it" is implied by the tense. An action taking place NOW that began in the past makes the use of adjacent verb tenses unclear, redundant and awkward.

**Edit: I started to suspect that something was up.**

Past-tense to infinitive is the most clear and concise.

Comment: "I was starting" may be long-winded, but it is **not** passive. (Well, it may be passive-aggressive).

Comment: [Please stop calling things passive which are ***not passive*** in any fashion whatsoever.](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2922)